# SQL unique column based on other columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, unique-constraint

I have a SQL Server database table that I am trying to fix without having to resort to using the front end code to determine if the name of the institute is unique. I am setting up a Linq to SQL code base for all of the inserts.

here is the new table that I am trying to setup:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[institution]
(
    [institutionID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    [typeID] [tinyint] NOT NULL REFERENCES [dbo].[institutiontype]([institutiontypeID]),
    [name] [varchar](255) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    [cityID] [int] NULL REFERENCES [dbo].[city]([cityID]),
    [stateID] [int] NULL REFERENCES [dbo].[stateprovince]([stateID]),
    [countryID] [int] NULL REFERENCES [dbo].[country]([countryID]),
    [createby] [int] NOT NULL REFERENCES [dbo].[ipamuser]([ipamuserID]),
    [createdatetime] [datetime] NOT NULL DEFAULT (GETDATE()),
    [modifyby] [int] NULL REFERENCES [dbo].[ipamuser]([ipamuserID]),
    [modifydatetime] [datetime] NULL,
    [dataversion] [int] NOT NULL DEFAULT (0)
)
```

The issue is, the institutionname needs to be unique ONLY when the cityID, stateID and the countryID are the same. Setting up the table with the institutename as unique will not satisfy the needs since there are times when the same name can exist in different, cities, states or countries.

How would I resolve this

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? Please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: I stated both in the content and tags that it is a SQL database

Comment: @mattgcon: **every** relational DBMS is a "SQL database". SQL is a query language not a DBMS product. But based on the non-standard SQL in your question this is SQL Server (T-SQL)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name thank you for the explanation.

Comment: @marc_s apologies for the rudeness

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to write a complex constraint in your table. Define a user-defined-function which returns true (1 in BIT) if your required condition is satisfied and false otherwise.
Put this constraint in the table schema with a `CHECK` constraint.

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.fnIsNameUnique (
  @name [varchar](255),
  @cityID int,
  @stateID int,
  @countryID int,
)
RETURNS tinyint
AS
BEGIN
  DECLARE @Result tinyint
  IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM institution WHERE name = @name AND cityID = @cityID AND stateID = @stateID AND countryID = @countryID)
    SET @Result= 0
  ELSE 
    SET @Result= 1
  RETURN @Result
END

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[institution]
(
    [institutionID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    [typeID] [tinyint] NOT NULL REFERENCES [dbo].[institutiontype]([institutiontypeID]),
    [name] [varchar](255) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    [cityID] [int] NULL REFERENCES [dbo].[city]([cityID]),
    [stateID] [int] NULL REFERENCES [dbo].[stateprovince]([stateID]),
    [countryID] [int] NULL REFERENCES [dbo].[country]([countryID]),
    [createby] [int] NOT NULL REFERENCES [dbo].[ipamuser]([ipamuserID]),
    [createdatetime] [datetime] NOT NULL DEFAULT (GETDATE()),
    [modifyby] [int] NULL REFERENCES [dbo].[ipamuser]([ipamuserID]),
    [modifydatetime] [datetime] NULL,
    [dataversion] [int] NOT NULL DEFAULT (0),
    CONSTRAINT ckValidName CHECK (
    dbo.fnIsNameUnique(name, cityID, stateID, countryID) = 1)
  )
)
```

Comment: Thank you, quick question. Shouldn't the "RETURNS" line be "RETURNS int" ?

Comment: Ok thank you. So let me understand this. When the LINQ insert statement runs in code, if the constraint = 0 then the SQL database automatically inserts the record, but if the constraint returns 1 what exactly happens? Do I have to handle anything on the code side for that?

Comment: It should be the other way round. If the `CHECK` udf returns 1, it works fine, the check returns zero and fails itself if you try to enter a record that doesn't qualify the constraint.

Comment: when I run the front end code I am receiving the following error: The INSERT statement conflicted with the CHECK constraint "ckValidName". The conflict occurred in database "ipam_era_test", table "dbo.institution".
The statement has been terminated.

Comment: yes. that's how a constraint doesn't let you insert or update stuff in your table.

Comment: Thanks for marking it as an answer. Better late than never :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you need anything so complex, just putting a UNIQUE constraint or index on `([name], CityID, StateID, CountryID)` does what you say you need.